# knockoutjs mapping to JSON multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, knockout.js

I've bundled two independent lists (requests and companies) into one JSON object and I'm trying to map it to my two knockout objects on the JavaScript side.

Originally, I only passed one list at a time (without the array name in the JSON) or the include line in the mapping functions, and it worked just fine.
As soon as I added the array name (ex. "RequestList" = ) to the JSON, it stopped working. Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/yth4vx0z/1/

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:requests">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:RequestID"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:companies">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:CompanyID"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is the JavaScript code:

```
    var myViewModel;
    $(function () {

        myViewModel = new viewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
        myViewModel.load();
    });

    var requestModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    }

    var companyModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    }

    var viewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.requestMapping = {
        include: ['RequestList'],
                create: function (options) {
                    return new requestModel(options.data);
                }
        };

        self.companyMapping = {
        include: ['CompanyList'],
                create: function (options) {
                    return new companyModel(options.data);
                }
        };

        self.requests = ko.observableArray();
        self.companies = ko.observableArray();

        self.load = function () {

            $.ajax(
            {
        json: ko.toJSON(fakeData)

        success: function (data) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.requestMapping, self.requests);
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.companyMapping, self.companies);
                },

                error: function () { 
                }
            });
        }
    }

var fakedata = 
    "RequestList": [
        {

        "RequestID": 12,
        "ContactID": 29
    }
],
"CompanyList": [
    {
        "CompanyID": 28,
        "Name": "CoName"
    },
    {
        "CompanyID": 29,
        "Name": "Name"
    }
]
```

Comment: A workaround that I found is to simply pass a subset of the data object to the mapping function: ko.mapping.fromJS(data["RequestList"], self.requestMapping, self.requests);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of small errors in your markup that is not allowing the script to work apart from the mapping issue, and I can't truly understand why you are trying to do a mapping for objects that don't have similar definition ... like for example Request JS object has RequestID and Name while the view model does not contain any of these fields ...

I have cleaned up your code to work with the mapping and you can see a working sample here 
https://jsfiddle.net/ka4b1591/23/

with that said tho, I recommend that you just use simple mapping to convert the JS object to View Models using the approach below.

```
var fakeData = {
    "RequestList": [
        {
            "RequestID": 12,
            "ContactID": 29
        }
    ],
    "CompanyList": [
        {
            "CompanyID": 28,
            "Name": "CoName"
        },
        {
            "CompanyID": 29,
            "Name": "Name"
        }
    ]};

var myView = ko.mapping.fromJS(fakeData);

$(document).ready(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(myView);
});
```

and the html

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:RequestList">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:RequestID"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:CompanyList">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:CompanyID"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

refer to the script on https://jsfiddle.net/fwq46ojf/3/

no need to do any view definition if you are just planning on using the JS fields

Comment: Thanks for your input  Sam. I provided the barebones of my project as an example, including only a few example fields. Say that I'd like to display a list of requests in a table. However, the request list only includes the companyID but not company name. In addition, that same page will allow a user to select new companies from a dropdown. I combined the the several lists into one Ajax call because I was told its better for the data requests to be chunky than chatty.